# Compare word documents(.docx) with a document template(.dotx)

Tags: c#, openxml

Is there any way I can compare a word document(.docx) with a document template(.dotx) generated in microsoft word.

I want to do this comparison programmatically using c#.

I want to compare both documents word to word so that I can determine to which template the document belongs. I don't just want to compare the size of both but I want to compare the contents also.

By this comparison I want get the following results.

1. From which document template the document is generated.
2. In the document template, I want to check that at which place a particular information is stored.

   Say for example I want to search for the communication information of a person, then I want to traverse the document and check that At which position the template has the area/section for Address.(i.e. Top left corner, top center, In a paragraph, In body etc)
3. In same way I want to extract other information too, Like Link to other documents etc.
4. After getting those positions I want to get that Information from the .Docx file.

   Say, If I found that the Address in the top-left and there are five links referring to other documents in five different paragraphs. Then what I want is to get the Address and save it to a variable. After that I want to replace those link contents from placeholders to Actual hyperLinks. i.e If a Link is referring to Doc-A then Instead of just showing a Plain text I want replace it with A hyperlink to Doc-A.

Any suggestions?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather too vague and involved to give a really good answer, however...

1. To find out from which template a document was generated the object model provides the property: Document.AttachedTemplate with will return the full file name. This is certainly better than comparing word-by-word (which is also very time-consuming)
2. The Word object model also provides the method CompareDocuments (belongs to the Word.Application class). This will "highlight" differences in the text content of two documents.
3. Links will be found in the Document.Hyperlinks collection
4. Getting the position of things is a bit chancy with Word and it depends on what you really mean by "top-left", etc. Better would be to construct the templates using content controls, form fields and/or bookmarks so that you can uniquely identify important sections. However, Word does provide the Range.get_Information method that can return relative and absolute positions on the page if that's what you really want.